# Attr_accessor and subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-accessor

I have User model and two subclasses Developer and Buyer(sub models). In each model i have constant FIELDS.

In model User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor *:get_fields

  after_initialize :get_additional_fields

  # FIELDS for current class
    def self.get_fields
      Object.const_get( self.name )::FIELDS
    end

  # set additional fields
  #
    def get_additional_fields
      self.country = 'text'
    end
end
```

I have some error `NoMethodError: undefined methodcountry=' for #<Developer:`

What is my error?

UPDATE

```
class Buyer < User
  FIELDS = [ :country, :avatar ]
end

class Developer < User
  FIELDS = [ :country, :avatar, :location, :first_name, :last_name ]
end
```

my request `d = Developer.first`

Comment: You're calling attr_acessor with a single symbol (:get_fields). Even if you fix that I think you'll find that at the point where you call attr accessor the get_fields method doesn't exist yet

Comment: ok, but how i can get list symbols from subclass?